# Downloading/Uploading file, what characters to filter c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file, filtering

In my application I build a static string when a user uploads or downloads a file. In that string the filename is passed from the frontend in that string. In this way the user could do things like ..\..\another file.file to tamper and get data from other users. Therefor I need to filter the filename that I get to prevent this. What are the characters that need to be filtered to prevent tampering? I now have the double dot and the back and forward slashes. Is there anything else I should take into consideration? Is there maybe a standard way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [`Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx):

```
public static bool IsValidFileName(string fileName)
{
    return fileName.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) == -1;
}
```

`..` is typically only dangerous when preceded and/or succeeded by a `\` or `/`, both of which are included in the array returned by `GetInvalidFileNameChars`. By itself, `..` is harmless (unless you’re specifically resolving directory paths), and you shouldn’t forbid it since people might want to introduce ellipses in their filename (e.g. `The A...Z of Programming.pdf`).

Answer (score 2):

What if different users save a file with the same name?  Are you creating a folder for each user?

Most likely what you should be doing is storing the name they provide in a database record, which also contains a pointer to the actual file (which uses a file name which you generate, perhaps a guid).   You could also consider using the filestream data type if you'd like to save the document in the database as well.

Nothing good can come from letting your users determine file names on your server :)

Comment: If it would be possible to work with a database I would have choosen that sollution. For now filtering is my second best option.